# WordPress creating table with dbDelta not working in plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a problem with my custom WordPress plugin creating a table with dbDelta. For creation I've created a function that returns my table when I call dbDelta:

```
private function get_db_schema(): string {
    $collate = '';

    if ( $this->wpdb->has_cap( 'collation' ) ) {
        $collate = $this->wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    }

    return "
    CREATE TABLE {$this->wpdb->prefix}woomex_exported_orders (
        id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        order_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        status varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        payment_status varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
        invoice_status varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
        cancellation_invoice_status varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
        delivery_status varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
        date_exported timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $collate;
    ";
}
```

After that I'm calling:

```
dbDelta( $this->get_db_schema() );
```

I'm getting no errors but also no table. I'm sure my function get's called because I verified this by a logging in it. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?